# Need to integrate apple pay with stripe

Tags: ios, react-native, applepay

I need to integrate apple pay with stripe. I have used `react-native-payments` package.
Also I have also installed `react-native-payments-addon-stripe` and `react-native-payments-cli`.

But I am getting error like **[ReactNativePayments] Failed to construct 'PaymentRequest':  "stripe" is not a supported gateway.**

My method data is like below, and I am using `react-native-payments` for sending `paymentRequest` like `const PaymentRequest = require('react-native-payments').PaymentRequest;`.

```
const METHOD_DATA = [{
            supportedMethods: ['apple-pay'],
            data: {
                merchantIdentifier: 'merchant.com.myapp.test',
                supportedNetworks: ['visa', 'mastercard', 'discover', 'amex'],
                countryCode: 'US',
                currencyCode: 'USD',
                paymentMethodTokenizationParameters: {
                    parameters: {
                        gateway: 'stripe',
                        'stripe:publishableKey': STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY

                    }
                }
            }
        }];
```

Can anyone please help me on this?
I have tried too many solutions but not getting solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at tipsi-stripe

Comment: isn't is possible with react-native-payments ?